# Python using higher order functions

Tags: python

I am trying to populate a 3D list in the following fashion:

```
l1 = []
for _ in range(5):
    l2 = []
    for _ in range(10):
        l2.append([0] * 20)
    l1.append(l2)
```

It looks really disgusting and I feel like there should be some way to use higher order function or anon functions or list comprehension to achieve this. Can any python ninjas show me how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> l1 == [[[0]*20]*10]*5
True
```

But this way there is aliasing - for example changing `a[0][1][2]` would also change `a[4][5][2]`, to avoid it, copies are necessary:

```
[[[0]*20 for i in range(10)] for j in range(5)]
```

Comment: NO. This is is a list of 5 references to a list of 10 references to a third list of 20 zeros. A total of three lists is created. `l1[0] is l1[1]`, `l1[0][0] is l1[1][2]`, etc. Demonstration: https://gist.github.com/anossov/5000464

Comment: @Jin, Do consider looking into `numpy` like Lev suggested. The learning curve is steeper than Python, but I bet now that you have your 3D list, your next question is going to be "Okay now how do I..." and the answer is going to be "use `numpy`".

Comment: @Jon-Eric I will def look into numpy next after I figure out where I'm going with this :]

Answer (score 3):

You can consider using `numpy` if you plan on "vectorized" calculations:

```
l1 = np.zeros((5, 10, 20))
```

[The docs.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer & help! straight list comprehension is enough for my case, but will def keep that in mind for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[[[0]*20 for _ in xrange(10)] for _ in xrange(5)]
```

The answer initially given by @zch has a *very* serious problem: it copies the same list over and over in the resulting matrix, so changes in one position will be reflected simultaneously in other unrelated positions!

My solution is indeed equivalent to your definition of `l1`, but written a bit more concisely thanks to the use of list comprehensions. Notice that we're not using the iteration variables, so it's ok to use `_` as placeholder. And, assuming you're using Python 2.x, it's a better idea to use `xrange` because we don't need the list created by `range`. (If using Python 3.x, it's ok to use `range`)